# Displaying only one result in a for loop in java

Tags: java, email

I am sending a mail from java. The issue is that I get only the last record of data in my mail when I run the program from the for loop. But when I print the data on the console, I get all records as expected.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < stud.size(); i++) {

        Student students = studs.get(i);

        msg.setContent("<table border = '1'><tr>"
                + "<th>Students</th><th>Project</th></tr>"
                + "<tr> <td> "
                + students.getFullname() + "</td>"
                + "<td> " + students.getProject() + "</td>"
                + "</tr></table>", "text/html"); // this sends only the last record on mail.

        System.out.println(students.getFullname() + " " + students.getProject()); // this prints a list of records on console.

    }

    Transport.send(msg);
```

Comment: If I move send() to the loop, it sends multiple mails. Not correct.

Comment: Its pretty Simple.
Whatever data you are looking for append it in a StringBuilder (You can verify the string value) Then after loop set it as content body and send it :)

Please mark it as solved if problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

`Transport.send(msg);` put this inside the for loop as well. Like so,

```
   private String myBody = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < stud.size(); i++) {

        Student students = studs.get(i);

        myBody += "<table border = '1'><tr>"
                + "<th>Students</th><th>Project</th></tr>"
                + "<tr> <td> "
                + students.getFullname() + "</td>"
                + "<td> " + students.getProject() + "</td>"
                + "</tr></table>", "text/html"); // this sends only the last record on mail.

        System.out.println(students.getFullname() + " " + students.getProject()); // this prints a list of records on console.

    }

    msg.setContent(myBody);
    Transport.send(msg);
```

Comment: Or maybe use the loop to concatenate content and set/send after the loop, so that you'll not send hundreds of mails to the same people, but just one with all data

Comment: Maybe he wants to send different mails to different people? Like one mail to  each of the students?

Comment: Maybe, but then why the recipient of the mail doesn't change in the loop?

Comment: Then you should append the content of the msg body. I've edited my answer (assuming there is a method called `msg.getContent()`

Comment: No, there are not any method getCOntent()

Comment: Ok. I have edited my answer yet again. This would surely work

Comment: @don234 Please find my answer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's the type of `msg`, but `msg.setContent` probably overwrites the previous value you set to it.

Assuming you wish to send a single email, try something like :

```
    msg.setContent(msg.getContent () + "<table border = '1'><tr>"
            + "<th>Students</th><th>Project</th></tr>"
            + "<tr> <td> "
            + students.getFullname() + "</td>"
            + "<td> " + students.getProject() + "</td>"
            + "</tr></table>", "text/html");
```

Alternately, there may be an `addContent()` or `appendContent()` method you can use instead of `setContent()`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on your code. You iterate over list of students setting mail content to the same message every time.

Then, after the loop you send the message that at this moment contains the last message only.

If you want to send several messages move `Transport.send(msg)` into the loop.

Comment: No, I want to send only one mail with the table being populated with the list of students.

Comment: So, concatenate your string using either string concatenation or StringBuilder.append() and then send one mail

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the `msg.setContent()` within the for loop. 
So you basically just override the content each time. The last iteration will be the actual content in the mail.
You might want to use a StringBuilder or something else to build the content first. Like so:

```
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < stud.size(); i++)
{
    content.append("<table border = '1'><tr>");
    content.append("<th>Students</th><th>Project</th></tr>");
    content.append("<tr> <td> ");
    content.append(students.getFullname() + "</td>");
    content.append("<td> " + students.getProject() + "</td>");
    content.append("</tr></table>");
}
msg.setContent(content.toString(), "text/html");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want only one email with all student record ,You need to create all string by concatenation or stringbuilder  like below.

```
String headerStirng = "<table border = '1'><tr>" + "<th>Students</th><th>Project</th></tr>";

        StringBuilder bodyString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < stud.size(); i++) {

            Student students = studs.get(i);

            bodyString.append("<tr> <td> " + students.getFullname() + "</td>" + "<td> " + students.getProject() + "</td></tr>");

            System.out.println(students.getFullname() + " " + students.getProject());

        }

        String footerStirng = "</table>";
        msg.setContent(headerStirng + bodyString + footerStirng, "text/html");
        Transport.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your loop, you are overwriting 'content' in each iteration of for loop.
Better to use StringBuffer / StringBuilder to concatenate String in each iteration of loop and finally set content.

```
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(); 
    buf.append("<table border = '1'>");
    for(int i = 0; i < stud.size(); i++) {

        Student students = studs.get(i);

       buf.append("<tr>"
                + "<th>Students</th><th>Project</th></tr>"
                + "<tr> <td> "
                + students.getFullname() + "</td>"
                + "<td> " + students.getProject() + "</td>"
                + "</tr>"); 

        System.out.println(students.getFullname() + " " + students.getProject()); 

    }
    buf.append("</table>");
    msg.setContent(buf.toString, "text/html");
    Transport.send(msg);
```